# Is there an easy way to compile illumos components on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, solaris-10, illumos

I am trying to compile some components from ptools from illumos source code on Solaris 10, and so far it has been difficult since the build components are not available and the make files in the component (containing the target program) folders do not run. Its like piecing together a jigsaw puzzle, searching for the appropriate definitions to complete gcc compilation. I wonder if there is any easier way.

Comment: Do you require Solaris 10 or can you use an illumos based distribution?

Comment: I need Solaris 10.

Comment: Are the versions of the ptools already provided in /usr/proc/bin on Solaris 10 not enough?

Comment: I am trying to understand how the tools and the proc files work, hence I was wanting to be able to examine functional source.

Comment: There's no easy way - if you can do it at all.  It'd be like trying to compile something for systemd on Red Hat 5.  There are significant kernel- and user-space changes introduced back in the Open Solaris days that became part of both Solaris 11 and Illumos.  Those changes aren't in Solaris 10.  The `ptools` in Solaris 10 work pretty much the same way as those in Open Solaris, Illumos, and Solaris 11 do.  But the underlying kernel and `/proc` structures in Solaris 10 are signficantly different, as are the user-space tools used for building.

Comment: The question then becomes -- What is the closest available ptools source code for solaris 10?

Comment: @user55570 - What specific functionality are you trying to duplicate?

Comment: pargs mainly and want to see where how long program args are handled

Comment: For `pargs`, there's an initial argument vector address in `/proc/.../psinfo` that can be used if you access the address space of the process to extract the arguments passed to the process.  I don't think that changed from Solaris 10 to Solaris 11, so the method used in Solaris 11 probably works fine under 10, even if the 11 code for pargs won't compile under 10.  Read the `proc.4` man page closely:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5174/proc-4.html#REFMAN4proc-4

Comment: The `psinfo.pr_argv` vector does not consistently work. There are a number of instances where it does not give a valid address.

Comment: Could there be a difference caused by the address model of the process being examined?  I don't recall if 64- and 32-bit processes have different layouts for `/proc` files, but I suspect they do.  Unfortunately I don't have access to a Solaris box right now.

Comment: in case you are interested, there is a vritualbox vm instance for solaris 10 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/vmtemplates-vmvirtualbox-1949721.html